# Integration test of Jersey web services using Spring for dependency injection fails to initialize @Context HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, jersey-2.0, jersey-test-framework

I have jersey web services that uses spring for dependency injection (spring-jersey module) and hibernate for object-relational mapping (ORM). In order to develop
integration tests taking into account the following conditions:

1. Intiailize the test container only once for entire test class
2. Register custom listeners, filters, servlets etc to the test
   container
3. Make sure that **@Context** HttpServletRequest is not null

According to this https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2412 Jersey project JIRA task **HttpServletRequest** is null and that's as shown in the resolution of the task **Works as desgined**. 
When running integration tests on Grizzly container, it runs the integration tests on **http** server hence, any dependence on **servlet-based** features such
as **HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, etc.** is not available.

There seems to be no standard solution on how to address this issue, and **Jersey** community is obviously open to such features being developed by contributors as 
stated in this https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2417 JIRA ticket. Until this feature is implemented, what are the possible workaround solutions? Based on my 
research I come cross a few posts that state:

1. Use external container (What if I don't want too?)
2. Use jersey's jetty module (What if I don't want to use Jetty?)
3. SpringMVC specific solutions that do not apply to this project (for we don't use Spring MVC)

So, what's the best solution to successfully run integration tests on jersey-based web servers that uses spring-jersey bridge for dependency injection and rely on
**Servlet-based** features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard behaviour from Jersey and the to allow **servlet-based** features such as **HttpServletRequest** is not available yet. Based on my research,
I could achieve the following conditions

1. Intiailize the test container only once for entire test class
2. Register custom listeners, filters, servlets etc to the test
       container
3. Make sure that @Context HttpServletRequest is not null

By starting/stopping A grizzly container manually and deploying the grizzly container instance on a custom jersey-based WebappContext. The steps are as follow in
case anyone else come across such issue

1. Create a HttpServer
2. In @Before create a custom **WebappContext** which reflects your
   **web.xml** and deploy your HttpServer instance using the **WebappContext**
3. In order to make sure that **Servlet-based** features such as
   **HttpServletRequest** are available during integration test use the **ServletRegistration** to load your application inside A **Servlet container** as shown below

**Step #1**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
public class ResourceEndpointIntegrationTest{
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest httpReq;

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ResourceEndpointIntegrationTest.class);

    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8989/";
    private static HttpServer server = null;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initTest() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:8989/";
    }
...
}
```

Use **SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class** and **@ContextConfiguration** to load the **applicationContext.xml** for tests. Also declare **@Context HttpServletRequest** and create
an instance of **HttpServer** to be used later. I use **@BeforeClass** here for Rest-Assured specific purposes (you don't have to use it), its optional.

**Step #2**

```
@Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        if (server == null) {
            System.out.println("Initializing an instance of Grizzly Container ...");
            final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig(ResourceEndpointIntegrationTest.class, ..., ..., ...); //update

            WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext("IntegrationTestContext");
                        //register your listeners from web.xml in here
            ctx.addListener("com.xxx.yyy.XEndpointServletContextListener");
                        //register your applicationContext.xml here
            ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:applicationContext.xml");

                        //ServletRegistration is needed to load the ResourceConfig rc inside ServletContainer or you will have no 
                        //Servlet-based features available 
            ServletRegistration registration = ctx.addServlet("ServletContainer",
                    new ServletContainer(rc));

                        //Initialize the Grizzly server passing it base URL
            server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI));

                        //Deploy the server using our custom context
            ctx.deploy(server);
        }
    }
```

The **setup** in **@Before** is run for every test but, the if condition will force the **setup** method to act like **@BeforeClass** allowing us to initialize the 
server once for the entire test class minus the **static** nature of **@BeforeClass**.

The reason I initialize the server once for all tests inside a test class is because, if we don't then we will have the following workflow

1. A server is started
2. Spring starts scanning for beans
3. Spring does autowired
4. Spring setups sessionFactory, etc.
5. The test is run
6. Spring destroys the context
7. Server is shutdown
8. Repeat step #1 to #7 for every test

Above is very time consuming and technically not feasible, hence initialize container once (which is why I don't extend **JerseyTest** because I want to control the startup/shutdown of the test container).

**#Step 3**

```
@AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Integration tests completed. Tear down the server ...");
        if (server != null && server.isStarted()) {
            server.shutdownNow();
            System.out.println("Grizzly instance shutdown completed");
        }
    }
```

In step 3 we use **@AfterClass** to shutdown the grizzly instance used for integration testing purposes.

And a sample test looks as follow

```
@Test
    public void testCreateSomethingReturnSuccessfully() {
        JSONObject something = new JSONObject();
        cust.put("name", "integrationTest");
        cust.put("age", 33);

        given().
            contentType(ContentType.JSON).
            body(something.toString()).post("/someEndpoint").
        then().
            statusCode(200).
        assertThat().
            body("id", greaterThan(0)).
            body("name", equalTo("integrationTest")).
            body("age", equalTo(33));
    }
```

(Gradle) Some of the relevent depdendencies

```
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-servlet', version: '2.23.2'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers', name:'jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2', version:'2.23.2'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name:'spring-test', version:'4.3.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'io.rest-assured', name:'rest-assured', version:'3.0.1'


// Spring
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '4.3.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '4.3.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '4.3.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '4.3.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '4.3.2.RELEASE'

    // Jersey-Spring bridge
    compile (group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext', name: 'jersey-spring3', version: '2.23.2'){
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-core'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-web'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-beans'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-jdbc'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-orm'
    }
```

Some of the imports

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;

import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
```